# Ansible fails at ad-hoc tasks midway with Error: data could not be sent to remote host

Tags: ssh, ansible, timeout, connectivity, intermittent

SSH connectivity from Ansible host to both my target servers is tested and working fine.

I tried the below but the solutions do not help.

```
1. $ export ANSIBLE_SCP_IF_SSH=y 
2. retries: 3
3. async: 1000
   poll:10
```

The playbook fails at any random task even when it is in a loop performing tasks.

Sample playbook code tried with both `ignore_errors: yes` and `ignore_errors: no`:

```
---
- name: "Play 1-Find the details here {{ Source_IP }} & {{ Dest_IP }} and {{ USER }}"
    
  hosts: "{{ domain_home }}"
  user: "{{ USER }}"
  any_errors_fatal: false
  gather_facts: true
  ignore_unreachable: yes

   - name: Take backup of existing files
     ignore_errors: yes
     shell: "cp /web/bea_apps/applications/{{ domain_home }}/{{ clustername }}/{{ vars[ ( item | basename ).split('.')[1] ] }}/{{ item | basename }} /web/bea_apps/applications/{{ domain_home }}/{{ clustername }}/{{ vars[ ( item | basename ).split('.')[1] ] }}/{{ item | basename }}_{{ tdate }}"
     retries: 3
     async: 1000
     poll: 10
     with_items: "{{ depexfiles.files | map(attribute='path') | list }}"
```

Error Output below:

```
failed: [FIRSTHOST] (item=/web/bea_apps/applications/mydom/myapp/CURRENT/UAT-04022021_01/canvel_bp.ear) => {"item": "/web/bea_apps/applications/mydom/myapp/CURRENT/UAT-04022021_01/canvel_bp.ear", "msg": "SSH Error: data could not be sent to remote host \"FIRSTHOST\". Make sure this host can be reached over ssh", "unreachable": true}
fatal: [FIRSTHOST]: UNREACHABLE! => {"changed": true, "msg": "All items completed", "results": [{"_ansible_ignore_errors": null, "_ansible_item_result": true, "_ansible_no_log": false, "_ansible_parsed": true, "changed": true, "cmd": "cp /web/bea_apps/applications/mydom/myapp/CURRENT/UAT-04022021_01/canvel_entity.ear /web/bea_apps/applications/mydom/myapp//canvel_entity.ear", "delta": "0:00:00.016825", "end": "2021-02-05 14:28:15.424165", "failed": false, "invocation": {"module_args": {"_raw_params": "cp /web/bea_apps/applications/mydom/myapp/CURRENT/UAT-04022021_01/canvel_entity.ear /web/bea_apps/applications/mydom/myapp//canvel_entity.ear", "_uses_shell": true, "chdir": null, "creates": null, "executable": null, "removes": null, "stdin": null, "warn": true}}, "item": "/web/bea_apps/applications/mydom/myapp/CURRENT/UAT-04022021_01/canvel_entity.ear", "rc": 0, "start": "2021-02-05 14:28:15.407340", "stderr": "", "stderr_lines": [], "stdout": "", "stdout_lines": []}, {"_ansible_ignore_errors": null, "_ansible_item_result": true, "_ansible_no_log": false, "_ansible_parsed": true, "changed": true, "cmd": "cp /web/bea_apps/applications/mydom/myapp/CURRENT/UAT-04022021_01/canvel_ipc.ear /web/bea_apps/applications/mydom/myapp//canvel_ipc.ear", "delta": "0:00:00.015333", "end": "2021-02-05 14:28:16.643801", "failed": false, "invocation": {"module_args": {"_raw_params": "cp /web/bea_apps/applications/mydom/myapp/CURRENT/UAT-04022021_01/canvel_ipc.ear /web/bea_apps/applications/mydom/myapp//canvel_ipc.ear", "_uses_shell": true, "chdir": null, "creates": null, "executable": null, "removes": null, "stdin": null, "warn": true}}, "item": "/web/bea_apps/applications/mydom/myapp/CURRENT/UAT-04022021_01/canvel_ipc.ear", "rc": 0, "start": "2021-02-05 14:28:16.628468", "stderr": "", "stderr_lines": [], "stdout": "", "stdout_lines": []}, {"_ansible_ignore_errors": null, "_ansible_item_result": true, "_ansible_no_log": false, "_ansible_parsed": true, "changed": true, "cmd": "cp /web/bea_apps/applications/mydom/myapp/CURRENT/UAT-04022021_01/canvel.ear /web/bea_apps/applications/mydom/myapp//canvel.ear", "delta": "0:00:00.169989", "end": "2021-02-05 14:28:17.994267", "failed": false, "invocation": {"module_args": {"_raw_params": "cp /web/bea_apps/applications/mydom/myapp/CURRENT/UAT-04022021_01/canvel.ear /web/bea_apps/applications/mydom/myapp//canvel.ear", "_uses_shell": true, "chdir": null, "creates": null, "executable": null, "removes": null, "stdin": null, "warn": true}}, "item": "/web/bea_apps/applications/mydom/myapp/CURRENT/UAT-04022021_01/canvel.ear", "rc": 0, "start": "2021-02-05 14:28:17.824278", "stderr": "", "stderr_lines": [], "stdout": "", "stdout_lines": []}, {"_ansible_ignore_errors": null, "_ansible_item_result": true, "item": "/web/bea_apps/applications/mydom/myapp/CURRENT/UAT-04022021_01/canvel_bp.ear", "msg": "SSH Error: data could not be sent to remote host \"FIRSTHOST\". Make sure this host can be reached over ssh", "unreachable": true}]}
failed: [SECONDHOST] (item=/web/bea_apps/applications/mydom/myapp/CURRENT/UAT-04022021_01/canvel_bp.ear) => {"item": "/web/bea_apps/applications/mydom/myapp/CURRENT/UAT-04022021_01/canvel_bp.ear", "msg": "SSH Error: data could not be sent to remote host \"SECONDHOST\". Make sure this host can be reached over ssh", "unreachable": true}
fatal: [SECONDHOST]: UNREACHABLE! => {"changed": true, "msg": "All items completed", "results": [{"_ansible_ignore_errors": null, "_ansible_item_result": true, "_ansible_no_log": false, "_ansible_parsed": true, "changed": true, "cmd": "cp /web/bea_apps/applications/mydom/myapp/CURRENT/UAT-04022021_01/canvel.ear /web/bea_apps/applications/mydom/myapp//canvel.ear", "delta": "0:00:00.152026", "end": "2021-02-05 14:28:14.573058", "failed": false, "invocation": {"module_args": {"_raw_params": "cp /web/bea_apps/applications/mydom/myapp/CURRENT/UAT-04022021_01/canvel.ear /web/bea_apps/applications/mydom/myapp//canvel.ear", "_uses_shell": true, "chdir": null, "creates": null, "executable": null, "removes": null, "stdin": null, "warn": true}}, "item": "/web/bea_apps/applications/mydom/myapp/CURRENT/UAT-04022021_01/canvel.ear", "rc": 0, "start": "2021-02-05 14:28:14.421032", "stderr": "", "stderr_lines": [], "stdout": "", "stdout_lines": []}, {"_ansible_ignore_errors": null, "_ansible_item_result": true, "_ansible_no_log": false, "_ansible_parsed": true, "changed": true, "cmd": "cp /web/bea_apps/applications/mydom/myapp/CURRENT/UAT-04022021_01/canvel_entity.ear /web/bea_apps/applications/mydom/myapp//canvel_entity.ear", "delta": "0:00:00.015997", "end": "2021-02-05 14:28:15.779838", "failed": false, "invocation": {"module_args": {"_raw_params": "cp /web/bea_apps/applications/mydom/myapp/CURRENT/UAT-04022021_01/canvel_entity.ear /web/bea_apps/applications/mydom/myapp//canvel_entity.ear", "_uses_shell": true, "chdir": null, "creates": null, "executable": null, "removes": null, "stdin": null, "warn": true}}, "item": "/web/bea_apps/applications/mydom/myapp/CURRENT/UAT-04022021_01/canvel_entity.ear", "rc": 0, "start": "2021-02-05 14:28:15.763841", "stderr": "", "stderr_lines": [], "stdout": "", "stdout_lines": []}, {"_ansible_ignore_errors": null, "_ansible_item_result": true, "_ansible_no_log": false, "_ansible_parsed": true, "changed": true, "cmd": "cp /web/bea_apps/applications/mydom/myapp/CURRENT/UAT-04022021_01/canvel_ipc.ear /web/bea_apps/applications/mydom/myapp//canvel_ipc.ear", "delta": "0:00:00.016255", "end": "2021-02-05 14:28:16.991029", "failed": false, "invocation": {"module_args": {"_raw_params": "cp /web/bea_apps/applications/mydom/myapp/CURRENT/UAT-04022021_01/canvel_ipc.ear /web/bea_apps/applications/mydom/myapp//canvel_ipc.ear", "_uses_shell": true, "chdir": null, "creates": null, "executable": null, "removes": null, "stdin": null, "warn": true}}, "item": "/web/bea_apps/applications/mydom/myapp/CURRENT/UAT-04022021_01/canvel_ipc.ear", "rc": 0, "start": "2021-02-05 14:28:16.974774", "stderr": "", "stderr_lines": [], "stdout": "", "stdout_lines": []}, {"_ansible_ignore_errors": null, "_ansible_item_result": true, "item": "/web/bea_apps/applications/mydom/myapp/CURRENT/UAT-04022021_01/canvel_bp.ear", "msg": "SSH Error: data could not be sent to remote host \"SECONDHOST\". Make sure this host can be reached over ssh", "unreachable": true}]}
        to retry, use: --limit @/web/playbooks/automation/deployments/deployfiles.retry

PLAY RECAP *******************************************************************************************
FIRSTHOST               : ok=20   changed=10   unreachable=1    failed=0
SECONDHOST               : ok=17   changed=8    unreachable=1    failed=0
```

I also tried setting `ignore_unreachable: yes` but i get the below error:

```
ERROR! 'ignore_unreachable' is not a valid attribute for a Play
```

Also posting the debug `-vvvv` for this failure:

```
<FIRSTHOST> (0, '\n{"changed": true, "end": "2021-02-05 16:21:47.477545", 
"stdout": "", "cmd": "cp
/web/bea_apps/applications/mydom/myapp//canvel.ear /web/bea_apps/applications/mydom/myapp//canvel.ear_bkp.05Feb2021_170451_04", "rc": 0, "start": "2021-02-05 16:21:47.333303"
, "stderr": "", "delta": "0:00:00.144242", "invocation": {"module_args": {"warn": true, "executable":
null, "_uses_shell": true, "_raw_params": "cp /web/bea_apps/applications/mydom/myapp//canvel
ocity.ear /web/bea_apps/applications/mydom/myapp//canvel.ear_bkp.05Feb2021_170451_04",
"removes": null, "creates": null, "chdir": null, "stdin": null}}}\n', 'OpenSSH_8.2p1 (CentrifyDC build
 5.7.0-207) , OpenSSL 1.1.1g  21 Apr 2020\r\ndebug1: Reading configuration data /home/anuser/.ssh/co
nfig\r\ndebug1: Reading configuration data /etc/centrifydc/ssh/ssh_config\r\ndebug1: /etc/centrifydc/s
sh/ssh_config line 3: Applying options for *\r\ndebug1: Authenticator provider $SSH_SK_PROVIDER did no
t resolve; disabling\r\ndebug2: resolving "FIRSTHOST" port 22\r\ndebug2: ssh_connect_direct\r\ndebu
g1: Connecting to FIRSTHOST [192.168.43.66] port 22.\r\ndebug2: fd 3 setting O_NONBLOCK\r\ndebug1:
fd 3 clearing O_NONBLOCK\r\ndebug1: Connection established.\r\ndebug3: timeout: 899959 ms remain after
 connect\r\ndebug1: identity file /home/anuser/.ssh/id_rsa type 0\r\ndebug1: identity file /home/ans
bladm/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1\r\ndebug1: identity file /home/anuser/.ssh/id_dsa type -1\r\ndebug1:
identity file /home/anuser/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1\r\ndebug1: identity file /home/anuser/.ssh/id_
ecdsa type -1\r\ndebug1: identity file /home/anuser/.ssh/id_ecdsa-cert type -1\r\ndebug1: identity f
ile /home/anuser/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk type -1\r\ndebug1: identity file /home/anuser/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk-c
ert type -1\r\ndebug1: identity file /home/anuser/.ssh/id_ed25519 type -1\r\ndebug1: identity file /
home/anuser/.ssh/id_ed25519-cert type -1\r\ndebug1: identity file /home/anuser/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk
type -1\r\ndebug1: identity file /home/anuser/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk-cert type -1\r\ndebug1: identity fi
le /home/anuser/.ssh/id_xmss type -1\r\ndebug1: identity file /home/anuser/.ssh/id_xmss-cert type
-1\r\ndebug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_8.2\r\ndebug1: Remote protocol version 2.0, remote
software version OpenSSH_7.9\r\ndebug1: match: OpenSSH_7.9 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000\r\ndebug2: f
d 3 setting O_NONBLOCK\r\ndebug1: Authenticating to FIRSTHOST:22 as \'wladmin\'\r\ndebug3: hostkeys
_foreach: reading file "/home/anuser/.ssh/known_hosts"\r\ndebug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECD
SA in file /home/anuser/.ssh/known_hosts:431\r\ndebug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from usdfw35as2
8v\r\ndebug3: order_hostkeyalgs: prefer hostkeyalgs: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sh
a2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sh
a2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521\r\ndebug3: send packet: type 20\r\ndebug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent\r\nde
bug3: receive packet: type 20\r\ndebug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received\r\ndebug2: local client KEXINIT pro
posal\r\ndebug2: KEX algorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecd
h-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sha2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,
diffie-hellman-group18-sha512,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,ext-info-c\r\ndebug2: host key algorithms:
 ecdsa-sha2-nistp256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521
-cert-v01@openssh.com,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,sk-ecdsa-sha2-nistp2
56-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,sk-ssh-ed25519-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-
512-cert-v01@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-256-cert-v01@openssh.com,ssh-rsa-cert-v01@openssh.com,sk-ecdsa-sha2-
nistp256@openssh.com,ssh-ed25519,sk-ssh-ed25519@openssh.com,rsa-sha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa,ssh-dss\
r\ndebug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@ope
nssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com\r\ndebug2: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes1
92-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com\r\ndebug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@open
ssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1
-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1\r\ndeb
ug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sh
a2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-25
6,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1\r\ndebug2: compression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib\r\ndebug2: compressi
on stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com,zlib\r\ndebug2: languages ctos: \r\ndebug2: languages stoc: \r\ndebug2:
 first_kex_follows 0 \r\ndebug2: reserved 0 \r\ndebug2: peer server KEXINIT proposal\r\ndebug2: KEX al
gorithms: curve25519-sha256,curve25519-sha256@libssh.org,ecdh-sha2-nistp256,ecdh-sha2-nistp384,ecdh-sh
a2-nistp521,diffie-hellman-group-exchange-sha256,diffie-hellman-group16-sha512,diffie-hellman-group18-
sha512,diffie-hellman-group14-sha256,diffie-hellman-group14-sha1\r\ndebug2: host key algorithms: rsa-s
ha2-512,rsa-sha2-256,ssh-rsa,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519\r\ndebug2: ciphers ctos: chacha20-poly130
5@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,aes256-gcm@openssh.com\r\ndebug2
: ciphers stoc: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com,aes128-ctr,aes192-ctr,aes256-ctr,aes128-gcm@openssh.com,
aes256-gcm@openssh.com\r\ndebug2: MACs ctos: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,umac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha
2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@openssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac
-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1\r\ndebug2: MACs stoc: umac-64-etm@openssh.com,u
mac-128-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-512-etm@openssh.com,hmac-sha1-etm@open
ssh.com,umac-64@openssh.com,umac-128@openssh.com,hmac-sha2-256,hmac-sha2-512,hmac-sha1\r\ndebug2: comp
ression ctos: none,zlib@openssh.com\r\ndebug2: compression stoc: none,zlib@openssh.com\r\ndebug2: lang
uages ctos: \r\ndebug2: languages stoc: \r\ndebug2: first_kex_follows 0 \r\ndebug2: reserved 0 \r\ndeb
ug1: kex: algorithm: curve25519-sha256\r\ndebug1: kex: host key algorithm: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256\r\ndebu
g1: kex: server->client cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none\r\ndeb
ug1: kex: client->server cipher: chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com MAC: <implicit> compression: none\r\nde
bug3: send packet: type 30\r\ndebug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_REPLY\r\ndebug3: receive packet: typ
e 31\r\ndebug1: Server host key: ecdsa-sha2-nistp256 SHA256:zOTWuGSy9Mefla1iLDAx+MKLWK1TBxa+W7yBoGPZY6
k\r\ndebug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/home/anuser/.ssh/known_hosts"\r\ndebug3: record_hostke
y: found key type ECDSA in file /home/anuser/.ssh/known_hosts:431\r\ndebug3: load_hostkeys: loaded 1
 keys from FIRSTHOST\r\ndebug3: hostkeys_foreach: reading file "/home/anuser/.ssh/known_hosts"\r\
ndebug3: record_hostkey: found key type ECDSA in file /home/anuser/.ssh/known_hosts:431\r\ndebug3: l
oad_hostkeys: loaded 1 keys from 192.168.43.66\r\ndebug1: Host \'FIRSTHOST\' is known and matches t
he ECDSA host key.\r\ndebug1: Found key in /home/anuser/.ssh/known_hosts:431\r\ndebug3: send packet:
 type 21\r\ndebug2: set_newkeys: mode 1\r\ndebug1: rekey out after 134217728 blocks\r\ndebug1: SSH2_MS
G_NEWKEYS sent\r\ndebug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS\r\ndebug3: receive packet: type 21\r\ndebug1: SSH
2_MSG_NEWKEYS received\r\ndebug2: set_newkeys: mode 0\r\ndebug1: rekey in after 134217728 blocks\r\nde
bug1: Will attempt key: /home/anuser/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:8n1t4uxiLvFE5icLLWjoAxpg785DZQjl++XUOpNd
Cwg\r\ndebug1: Will attempt key: /home/anuser/.ssh/id_dsa \r\ndebug1: Will attempt key: /home/ansbla
dm/.ssh/id_ecdsa \r\ndebug1: Will attempt key: /home/anuser/.ssh/id_ecdsa_sk \r\ndebug1: Will attemp
t key: /home/anuser/.ssh/id_ed25519 \r\ndebug1: Will attempt key: /home/anuser/.ssh/id_ed25519_sk
\r\ndebug1: Will attempt key: /home/anuser/.ssh/id_xmss \r\ndebug2: pubkey_prepare: done\r\ndebug3:
send packet: type 5\r\ndebug3: receive packet: type 7\r\ndebug1: SSH2_MSG_EXT_INFO received\r\ndebug1:
 kex_input_ext_info: server-sig-algs=<ssh-ed25519,ssh-rsa,rsa-sha2-256,rsa-sha2-512,ssh-dss,ecdsa-sha2
-nistp256,ecdsa-sha2-nistp384,ecdsa-sha2-nistp521,null>\r\ndebug3: receive packet: type 6\r\ndebug2: s
ervice_accept: ssh-userauth\r\ndebug1: SSH2_MSG_SERVICE_ACCEPT received\r\ndebug3: send packet: type 5
0\r\ndebug3: receive packet: type 53\r\ndebug3: input_userauth_banner\r\n\nThis system is for the use
by authorized users only. All data contained\non all systems is owned by the company and may be monito
red, intercepted,\nrecorded, read, copied, or captured in any manner and disclosed in any\nmanner, by
authorized company personnel. Users (authorized or unauthorized)\nhave no explicit or implicit expecta
tion of privacy. Unauthorized or improper\nuse of this system may result in administrative, disciplina
ry action, civil\nand criminal penalties. Use of this system by any user, authorized or\nunauthorized,
 constitutes express consent to this monitoring, interception,\nrecording, reading, copying, or captur
ing and disclosure.\n\nIF YOU DO NOT CONSENT, LOG OFF NOW.\n\n########################################
##########################\n# *** This Server is using Centrify                          *** #\n# ***
Remember to use your Active Directory account          *** #\n# ***    password when logging in
                     *** #\n##################################################################\n\ndebu
g3: receive packet: type 51\r\ndebug1: Authentications that can continue: publickey,password,keyboard-
interactive\r\ndebug3: start over, passed a different list publickey,password,keyboard-interactive\r\n
debug3: preferred gssapi-with-mic,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey\r\ndebug3: authmethod_lookup public
key\r\ndebug3: remaining preferred: ,gssapi-keyex,hostbased,publickey\r\ndebug3: authmethod_is_enabled
 publickey\r\ndebug1: Next authentication method: publickey\r\ndebug1: Offering public key: /home/ansb
ladm/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:8n1t4uxiLvFE5icLLWjoAxpg785DZQjl++XUOpNdCwg\r\ndebug3: send packet: type 5
0\r\ndebug2: we sent a publickey packet, wait for reply\r\ndebug3: receive packet: type 60\r\ndebug1:
Server accepts key: /home/anuser/.ssh/id_rsa RSA SHA256:8n1t4uxiLvFE5icLLWjoAxpg785DZQjl++XUOpNdCwg\
r\ndebug3: sign_and_send_pubkey: RSA SHA256:8n1t4uxiLvFE5icLLWjoAxpg785DZQjl++XUOpNdCwg\r\ndebug3: sig
n_and_send_pubkey: signing using rsa-sha2-512 SHA256:8n1t4uxiLvFE5icLLWjoAxpg785DZQjl++XUOpNdCwg\r\nde
bug3: send packet: type 50\r\ndebug3: receive packet: type 52\r\ndebug1: Authentication succeeded (pub
lickey).\r\nAuthenticated to FIRSTHOST ([192.168.43.66]:22).\r\ndebug2: fd 4 setting O_NONBLOCK\r\n
debug2: fd 5 setting O_NONBLOCK\r\ndebug2: fd 6 setting O_NONBLOCK\r\ndebug1: channel 0: new [client-s
ession]\r\ndebug3: ssh_session2_open: channel_new: 0\r\ndebug2: channel 0: send open\r\ndebug3: send p
acket: type 90\r\ndebug1: Requesting no-more-sessions@openssh.com\r\ndebug3: send packet: type 80\r\nd
ebug1: Entering interactive session.\r\ndebug1: pledge: network\r\ndebug3: receive packet: type 80\r\n
debug1: client_input_global_request: rtype hostkeys-00@openssh.com want_reply 0\r\ndebug3: receive pac
ket: type 4\r\ndebug1: Remote: /home/wladmin/.ssh/authorized_keys:2: key options: agent-forwarding por
t-forwarding pty user-rc x11-forwarding\r\ndebug3: receive packet: type 4\r\ndebug1: Remote: /home/wla
dmin/.ssh/authorized_keys:2: key options: agent-forwarding port-forwarding pty user-rc x11-forwarding\
r\ndebug3: receive packet: type 91\r\ndebug2: channel_input_open_confirmation: channel 0: callback sta
rt\r\ndebug2: fd 3 setting TCP_NODELAY\r\ndebug3: ssh_packet_set_tos: set IP_TOS 0x20\r\ndebug2: clien
t_session2_setup: id 0\r\ndebug1: Sending command: /bin/sh -c \'/usr/bin/python && sleep 0\'\r\ndebug2
: channel 0: request exec confirm 1\r\ndebug3: send packet: type 98\r\ndebug2: channel_input_open_conf
irmation: channel 0: callback done\r\ndebug2: channel 0: open confirm rwindow 0 rmax 32768\r\ndebug2:
channel 0: rcvd adjust 2097152\r\ndebug3: receive packet: type 99\r\ndebug2: channel_input_status_conf
irm: type 99 id 0\r\ndebug2: exec request accepted on channel 0\r\ndebug2: channel 0: read<=0 rfd 4 le
n 0\r\ndebug2: channel 0: read failed\r\ndebug2: channel 0: chan_shutdown_read (i0 o0 sock -1 wfd 4 ef
d 6 [write])\r\ndebug2: channel 0: input open -> drain\r\ndebug2: channel 0: ibuf empty\r\ndebug2: cha
nnel 0: send eof\r\ndebug3: send packet: type 96\r\ndebug2: channel 0: input drain -> closed\r\ndebug3
: receive packet: type 96\r\ndebug2: channel 0: rcvd eof\r\ndebug2: channel 0: output open -> drain\r\
ndebug2: channel 0: obuf empty\r\ndebug2: channel 0: chan_shutdown_write (i3 o1 sock -1 wfd 5 efd 6 [w
rite])\r\ndebug2: channel 0: output drain -> closed\r\ndebug3: receive packet: type 98\r\ndebug1: clie
nt_input_channel_req: channel 0 rtype exit-status reply 0\r\ndebug3: receive packet: type 97\r\ndebug2
: channel 0: rcvd close\r\ndebug3: channel 0: will not send data after close\r\ndebug2: channel 0: alm
ost dead\r\ndebug2: channel 0: gc: notify user\r\ndebug2: channel 0: gc: user detached\r\ndebug2: chan
nel 0: send close\r\ndebug3: send packet: type 97\r\ndebug2: channel 0: is dead\r\ndebug2: channel 0:
garbage collecting\r\ndebug1: channel 0: free: client-session, nchannels 1\r\ndebug3: channel 0: statu
s: The following connections are open:\r\n  #0 client-session (t4 r0 i3/0 o3/0 e[write]/0 fd -1/-1/6 s
ock -1 cc -1)\r\n\r\ndebug3: send packet: type 1\r\ndebug1: fd 0 clearing O_NONBLOCK\r\ndebug3: fd 1 i
s not O_NONBLOCK\r\ndebug1: fd 2 clearing O_NONBLOCK\r\nTransferred: sent 70724, received 4800 bytes,
in 0.6 seconds\r\nBytes per second: sent 123595.8, received 8388.4\r\ndebug1: Exit status 0\r\n')
changed: [FIRSTHOST] => (item=/web/bea_apps/applications/mydom/myapp/CURRENT/UAT-04022021_01/canvel.ear) => {
    "changed": true,
    "cmd": "cp /web/bea_apps/applications/mydom/myapp//canvel.ear /web/bea_apps/applications/mydom/myapp//canvel.ear_bkp.05Feb2021_170451_04",
    "delta": "0:00:00.144242",
    "end": "2021-02-05 16:21:47.477545",
    "invocation": {
        "module_args": {
            "_raw_params": "cp /web/bea_apps/applications/mydom/myapp//canvel.ear /web/bea_apps/applications/mydom/myapp//canvel.ear_bkp.05Feb2021_170451_04",
            "_uses_shell": true,
            "chdir": null,
            "creates": null,
            "executable": null,
            "removes": null,
            "stdin": null,
            "warn": true
        }
    },
    "item": "/web/bea_apps/applications/mydom/myapp/CURRENT/UAT-04022021_01/canvelocity.ear",
    "rc": 0,
    "start": "2021-02-05 16:21:47.333303",
    "stderr": "",
    "stderr_lines": [],
    "stdout": "",
    "stdout_lines": []
}
fatal: [FIRSTHOST]: UNREACHABLE! => {
    "changed": true,
    "msg": "All items completed",
    "results": [
        {
            "_ansible_ignore_errors": true,
            "_ansible_item_result": true,
            "_ansible_no_log": false,
            "_ansible_parsed": true,
            "changed": true,
            "cmd": "cp /web/bea_apps/applications/mydom/myapp//canvel_ipc.ear /web/bea_apps/applications/mydom/myapp//canvel_ipc.ear_bkp.05Feb2021_170451_04",
            "delta": "0:00:00.015079",
            "end": "2021-02-05 16:06:44.638831",
            "failed": false,
            "invocation": {
                "module_args": {
                    "_raw_params": "cp /web/bea_apps/applications/mydom/myapp//canvel_ipc.ear /web/bea_apps/applications/mydom/myapp//canvel_ipc.ear_bkp.05Feb2021_170451_04",

                    "_uses_shell": true,
                    "chdir": null,
                    "creates": null,
                    "executable": null,
                    "removes": null,
                    "stdin": null,
                    "warn": true
                }
            },
            "item": "/web/bea_apps/applications/mydom/myapp/CURRENT/UAT-04022021_0
1/canvel_ipc.ear",
            "rc": 0,
            "start": "2021-02-05 16:06:44.623752",
            "stderr": "",
            "stderr_lines": [],
            "stdout": "",
            "stdout_lines": []
        },
        {
            "_ansible_ignore_errors": true,
            "_ansible_item_result": true,
            "item": "/web/bea_apps/applications/mydom/myapp/CURRENT/UAT-04022021_0
1/canvel_entity.ear",
            "msg": "SSH Error: data could not be sent to remote host \"FIRSTHOST\". Make sure this
host can be reached over ssh",
            "unreachable": true
        },
        {
            "_ansible_ignore_errors": true,
            "_ansible_item_result": true,
            "_ansible_no_log": false,
            "_ansible_parsed": true,
            "changed": true,
            "cmd": "cp /web/bea_apps/applications/mydom/myapp//canvel_bp.ear /web/bea_apps/applications/mydom/myapp//canvel_bp.ear_bkp.05Feb2021_170451_04",

            "delta": "0:00:00.015381",
            "end": "2021-02-05 16:21:46.121933",
            "failed": false,
            "invocation": {
                "module_args": {
                    "_raw_params": "cp /web/bea_apps/applications/mydom/myapp//canvel_bp.ear /web/bea_apps/applications/mydom/myapp//canvel_bp.ear_bkp.05Feb
2021_170451_04",
                    "_uses_shell": true,
                    "chdir": null,
                    "creates": null,
                    "executable": null,
                    "removes": null,
                    "stdin": null,
                    "warn": true
                }
            },
            "item": "/web/bea_apps/applications/mydom/myapp/CURRENT/UAT-04022021_0
1/canvel_bp.ear",
            "rc": 0,
            "start": "2021-02-05 16:21:46.106552",
            "stderr": "",
            "stderr_lines": [],
            "stdout": "",
            "stdout_lines": []
        },
        {
            "_ansible_ignore_errors": true,
            "_ansible_item_result": true,
            "_ansible_no_log": false,
            "_ansible_parsed": true,
            "changed": true,
            "cmd": "cp /web/bea_apps/applications/mydom/myapp//canvel.ear /web/bea_apps/applications/mydom/myapp//canvel.ear_bkp.05Feb2021_170451_04",
            "delta": "0:00:00.144242",
            "end": "2021-02-05 16:21:47.477545",
            "failed": false,
            "invocation": {
                "module_args": {
                    "_raw_params": "cp /web/bea_apps/applications/mydom/myapp//canvel.ear /web/bea_apps/applications/mydom/myapp//canvel.ear_bkp.05Feb2021_170451_04",
                    "_uses_shell": true,
                    "chdir": null,
                    "creates": null,
                    "executable": null,
                    "removes": null,
                    "stdin": null,
                    "warn": true
                }
            },
            "item": "/web/bea_apps/applications/mydom/myapp/CURRENT/UAT-04022021_01/canvel.ear",
            "rc": 0,
            "start": "2021-02-05 16:21:47.333303",
            "stderr": "",
            "stderr_lines": [],
            "stdout": "",
            "stdout_lines": []
        }
    ]
}
        to retry, use: --limit @/web/playbooks/automation/deployments/deployfiles.retry

PLAY RECAP *******************************************************************************************
FIRSTHOST               : ok=19   changed=9    unreachable=1    failed=0
SECONDHOST               : ok=16   changed=7    unreachable=1    failed=0
```

Comment: Won't fix your issue, but an unreachable host is not an error, for Ansible. To ignore unreachable hosts, you'll have to use [`ignore_unreachable: yes`](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_error_handling.html#ignoring-unreachable-host-errors)

Comment: The host is very much reachable as I mentioned in the original post. Infact in a block if there are 3 tasks it may fail after performing two task of the same block on a given host. @β.εηοιτ.βε

Comment: That's what you'll have to guess, and with what is in your question, I doubt anyone would be able to guess it for you. Running your commands on extra verbose might help you understand it further: `-vvvv`

Comment: fine @β.εηοιτ.βε i m updating the original post with the output of `-vvvv` verbose Meanwhile the three solutions I tried are from users who got the very same runtime error as this seems like an issue for which multiple suggestions have been advised.

Comment: Updated the debug verbose `-vvvv` output in the original post.

Comment: What happens if you use the `copy` module (with `remote_src: yes`) rather than `cp` in shell?

Comment: @Zeitounator The issue is something else … changed to `copy` module and does not help as well. The playbook freezes at any point of time in the loop and give the same error I posted in the original post.